# Correct path for a client certificate in Xamarin PCL Android

Tags: android, path, xamarin, xamarin.forms, webrequest

I want to make a WebRequest out of my App and i need to add a Client-Certificate.
In my plain C# Solution I am using the following two lines for that:

```
X509Certificate myCert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(certPath);
request.ClientCertificates.Add(myCert);
```

The problem is that i don't know what i should use as "certPath" inside my App.
I am doing a Xamarin.Forms PCL Project and test it on Android.
I found out that for Android i have to put the File into the Assets folder of my Project, but i don't know what the correct Path is for the method parameter.
My Implementation for the WebRequest is in the Android specific part.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking. You say you found out that you have to put it in the Assets folder, so what do you still want to know? It still can't find the file? Have a look at this; http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/resources_in_android/part_6_-_using_android_assets/

Comment: My understanding of the AssetManager is that it makes it possible to access files (e.g. to read them). But for my method above i need the 'filename' (full path) of the file in the Asset dir to reach this file, and i dont know how to get this path

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i haven't got the path for the Files in the Project, but i found another solution:

1. Get any path of your app on the device/emulator from a directory where it's
   possible to get it:

   e.g. System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
2. Copy the Certificate manually to the device/emulator via DDMS (in
   Android Device Monitor) - exactly into the path that is shown by the
   method above.
3. Use this path including the filename you have copied for the
   certificate path.

I also found out that for me the certificate seems not to work in xamarin if it's in pkcs12 format, but i don't know why. I had converted it to pem.

I think after "importing" the certificate it's necessary to save it in a keystore or something like that and delete the file, but i'm not that far yet.